# Visual Studio 2019 .NET CORE and React Template Subsite

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I am having a hard time getting this template to work as a subsite.

The steps that I took to create the project were:

- Launch Visual Studio
- Create a new project
- Select ASP.NET Core Web Application
- Gave the details for where the project should be stored, etc
- Create
- At this time I am not interested in redux so I just selected the "React.js A project template for creating an ASP.NET core application with React.js"

After that I thought that the steps to make this work at a sub-site would be:

- Right-Click and Properties on the Web App Project, on the debug tab I set the App URL to what was there + /mysub, for example: http://localhost:57197/mysub
- Inside the Client App Folder I modified package.json and set the "homepage" to "/mysub"

When I debug the application nothing renders in the browser. The browser's console shows that it is getting invalid characters when trying to load resources such as manifest.json, and even bundle.js, which tells me that the client side router is probably intercepting the requests for those files, and when I look at the network tab it looks pretty more obvious that is what is going on. The strange thing is though that  tag does appear to be right and thus it is setting the %PUBLIC_URL% environment variable as I would expect, but for some reason it just will not work at this subsite location. I suspect that maybe there is more that I may need to do in Startup.cs, or even appsettings.json but I am not sure what that might be, or if even that is the route to go. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: do you want the process to create a project ASP.NET COre using reactJS.NET?  sorry to ask that, i want to be sure what you want.. i dont understand very well the english

Comment: what is your JS engine V8, Chacrakore..?

Comment: I just want to be able to debug my application @ http://localhost:57197/mysub. By JS engine, do you mean my nodejs version? node -v currently shows me a v14.5.0 on this machine that I am on.